# jQuery selector with RegEx not accepting expressions

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to get all elements with 'aria-label' attribute that contains special characters:

```html
<div aria-label="FromTo #abc124">Accept</div>
<div aria-label="FromTo #dd_13">Accept</div>
<div aria-label="FromTo #_bd33">Accept</div>
<div aria-label="FromTo #kld9L">Accept</div>
```

I would like to iterate those elements in jQuery, but every regular expression I've tried gave me unexpected expression error.

Some expressions I tried so far:

```
$('[aria-label="FromTo #*"]') // not working
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('aria-label').match(/FromTo \#.*/);
}) // not working
$(':contains([aria-label="FromTo [#\w+\d+]")') // not working
```

Nothing.

Comment: What makes you think JQuery accepts regex in selectors?

Comment: There are third-party plugins that add the ability to do regexp matching in selectors, but it's not built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectors don't test regular expressions, but you don't need it here. There's an "attribute starts with" selector, `attr^=string`.

```js
console.log($('div[aria-label^="FromTo #"]').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div aria-label="FromTo #abc124">Accept</div>
<div aria-label="FromTo #dd_13">Accept</div>
<div aria-label="FromTo #_bd33">Accept</div>
<div aria-label="FromTo #kld9L">Accept</div>
<div area-label="something else">Not accept</div>
<div>Not ARIA</div>
```